# Cloud Computing with Saas Stricly needed Cloud Server Hosting? Can we host Saas to VPN?

Tags: cloud, vpn, saas, cloud-hosting

I am working with a **SaaS** (Software as Service).

I want to know that is SaaS always need a **Cloud Server hosting**?

Can i provide **SaaS over VPN**? As i see more of answers with difference between

Dedicated Server vs Cloud Computing, but **where to host SaaS** as a **Provider**, VPN or Cloud Hosting for (SaaS) is the main issue.

I know clould hosting is the best way for SaaS but for **startup** it costs hard for **small business (Sass Provider)**.

Answer (score 0):

In SaaS, software's server response time plays an important role.
Your services should be available 24/7 with quick response. But for startups, cloud hosting is expensive as compare to VPS or Dedicated hosting. 
Yes, you can host SaaS over VPN, you just need to monitor your server's performance but whenever you face any issue related to hosting or server, that time you have to move to cloud.

Comment: After hosting software over VPN still be a cloud (saas) application?